# Jail building, escaping from a frictionless hemispherical pit bottom without initial velocity

Tags: physics

Imagine a frictionless and rigid hemispherical pit with a radius of 10m on the Earth. For a wizard in my world, it is easy to make such a pit, but hard to build a jail. The pit is the side effect of some space magic.

The prisoner is trapped at the bottom of the pit with no initial speed.
Can the prisoner escape the pit? Assume that air resistance and lifespan are factors. Breathing or using the Magnus Effect might take too long.

---

Space Magic Description: This is short-distance teleportation magic. In order to avoid collision between the teleported and the molecules being teleported, the molecules are squeezed outward thus forming an irregular frictionless rigid mirror surface.

The Wizard was not carrying something such as a rope on their person. Their task is to capture the enemies again and again and is not willing to spend more time on one enemy. These enemies were normal humans who could not do magic.

Please let me know if you need any clarification or more details.

Comment: Does he get a skateboard?

Comment: @RobertRapplean For safety, the skateboard can be confiscated

Comment: Of interest: [How would the world control an invulnerable immortal mass murderer?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/144138/55743).

Comment: @Voyager: thank you for keeping your pronouns gender-neutral. I wish commenters (on the question and the answers) would similarly avoid gender bias.

Comment: if it was a cylinder instead of a bowl, it would be inescapable

Comment: Not specifying "the prisoner" in a world with "wizards" makes my imagination run wild with creatures which could easily escape this

Comment: What do you mean by 'very strong', as in super strength?  Can a chain hold them?   Can they say jump 30 ft in the air?

Comment: Anything can be escaped with social engineering. You just wait until a bloke with a rope wanders past and say "Friend! I will give you ten gold sovereigns if you just lower me a rope! I'm totes good for the cash, ask anyone ... er except Wizard Dribble he hates me for some reason"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### They can escape.

It's basically the same principle as how one uses a swing without getting a push to start - a swing is essentially a 2D version of this setup, a semicircular pit with no frictional force in play, and an ability to exert net force only in the radial direction. Standing at the bottom of the pit, push your arms out in front of you. Your center of mass doesn't move, but your feet will slide backwards a little. Since there's no friction, your feet will oscillate underneath you, swinging back and forth over the center slightly. Now you just need to bend your knees and pump in time with the oscillations, which will make the swing larger and larger. Eventually, the swing is large enough to grab the lip of the pit. Even though the prisoner's center of mass is moving vertically and must remain above the pit when clearing the lip, the prisoner merely need extend his arms forward and legs backwards to get a handhold outside the pit without moving his center of mass outside the pit.

If you've ever used a swing set without someone pushing you to get started, you can get out of the pit. As another analogy, this is basically like riding a frictionless skateboard in a half-pipe. It is clearly possible to increase the amplitude of the oscillations, a competent skateboarder can jump much higher than the lip of the half-pipe where they enter, and they never need to push tangentially to the ground to do it.

Comment: How about lying down? Does the prisoner need professional training to stand up from the bottom of the pit and maintain a standing position without falling?

Comment: @Voyager I don't think standing will be terribly difficult, it's not like it's impossible to stand up on a sheet of ice, you just need to do it carefully. But even if it is, this approach still works lying down, you just need to pump your legs back and forth to get started and then pump your arms up and down to increase the swing.

Comment: BTW, @Voyager, it may be less important for a yes-or-no type question like this, but it's usually recommended to wait 24 hours or more before accepting an answer.  A check mark tends to discourage other answers, and might send away someone who's answer is actually better.

Comment: I think there's a flaw in this reasoning: if the pit is actually hemispheric, even if the prisoner manages to pump up enough momentum to reach the rim, at that point his velocity will be vertically upward, and he won't be able to get a grip on anything outside the pit to avoid simply falling back in -- and if he falls, the constantly changing difference between gravity and centripetal force over a pretty short period (less than a minute) will make rising when not still at the bottom impossible (IMO) until air drag stops him.

Comment: I don't think this works--swings have a maximum climb because eventually the energy lost to drag exceeds the energy you can add per cycle.  And I believe this pit is far beyond that limit.

Comment: @Voyager re lying down, you can still *sit up* even in a frictionless environment, even if you were initially face down as well. And after sitting up, starting to swing becomes decently easy.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Ever seen kiiking? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJkjyq_or70

Comment: @biziclop I said a maximum climb, not that you couldn't do a 360.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Once you are getting enough height for the rim of the hemisphere, you sit down, and then stretch out on your next "jump"; your legs stick out towards the centre of the pit, and your arms reach out to scrabble at the friction-full ground the pit is dug into?  You won't be able to use your legs to push yourself up, so you'll have to rely entirely on your arms to pull you out.

Comment: @Chronocidal if the jailer can make a frictionless hemispherical pit, I think it's safe to say they can also make the meter or two around the rim of the pit frictionless as well

Comment: @Tristan: There's "can", and there's "think about". They may not think about the necessity of doing so, if no prisoner ever escaped their contraption before.

Comment: @ZeissIkon That's what I thought at first too, but it is not a problem. At the top of the pit edge, the person's center of mass is moving straight up and remains above the pit. But that doesn't mean *no part* of him can extend past the lip of the pit, just that his center of mass can't without external force. He can extend his arms forward and push his legs back to grab outside the pit, and pull himself out (so long as there's friction/something to grab outside the pit).

Comment: @LorenPechtel I expect most of the energy lost in the swing is due to inefficiencies in the chain going somewhat slack as the swing approaches horizontal. This scenario is actually more like riding a half-pipe with a perfect frictionless skateboard - it's certainly possible to get a skateboard well above the lip of a half-pipe. Drag will only play a major role if the pit is huge, making the magnitude and duration of the drag very high.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure the analogy with a swing is correct, try standing on a swing or like @bizclop shows kiiking and getting it going without using your arms on the ropes or arms of the swing.  I do think it would work, but not nearly as easily as a swing because you can alter the forces by holding the ropes or arms and there is a static point at the top.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie It comes down to how much force per swing vs how much drag per swing.  I believe air drag in this scenario goes at the cube of diameter (Linear on the distance traveled, square on the velocity) while the input energy remains fixed.  The world record on Kiiking is 7.43 meters.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Kiiking involves a complete 360-degree rotation, but we only need 180 degrees. A 7.4m full rotation requires 50% more height/energy than a 10m half-rotation, so this suggests to me that a 10m half-rotation should certainly be doable, even if only for someone in good shape.

Answer (score 20):

#### Escape Proof (with a tiny change)

Geometry is our friend and physics a fun companion when it comes to devising a gaol that is not only escape proof, but also educational and entertaining into the bargain!

*There was once*, in the land of Angera a particularly eager archon by the name of Crowell whose sole delight, it seems, was devising what some might consider cruel and unusual means of punishing the wicked. But never let it be said that Crowell was a mean sort! For he was, at heart, a jolly old soul, and so jolly was he that he was determined to bring judicial jollity to his subjects.

Thus, let us examine old king Crowell's merry old bowl of judicial jollity! In construction, it is a roughly hemispherical bowl made from thick and crystal clear glass some eighteen feet in diametre. It is suspended from a platform above, for the convenience of the Guard, and also a shit hole at the bottom. The colonnade upon which the Cauldron is suspended allows the public a grand view of those stuck within!

Penitents are brought up to the platform, stripped naked, oiled and have their charges read out to them. Upon public approbation of the proceedings, the penitents are shoved into the bowl, from which they might only be fished out at death.

The key to the success of keeping penitents in is two fold: geometry tells us that a rounded shape is best for keeping the penitents down. There is really no flat surface upon which one might stand, and the curve of the bowl itself prevents climbing. Even if one could climb, the lack of a rim upon which to hoist oneself out and the steep neck of adverse camber prevents the escape from continuing.

Secondly, physics, that old prankster, teaches us that motion tends to continue in its own direction unless otherwise directed. So, if one tries to slide oneself out of the bowl as if riding a swing by constant back-and-forth motions of the body, the circular motion of the body will simply be guided by the slight incurve of the bowl, sending the miserable miscreant out into empty space, where from he shall plummet back into the bowl, with much cheering and jollity among the crowd!

Having learned this valuable lesson of physics, the penitent might consider himself Smart, and says: "I shall beat this device by physics of mine own!" And so thrusting himself to and fro again, he shall attempt to twist himself at the last moment in an attempt to grasp at the rim! Had Crowell and his geometers not considered this clever means of escape, the penitent might be successful! However, the smooth curve of the cauldron's neck and the angle of its slope spell doom for the penitent, and with further jeers and guffaws from the crowd, he shall, his fingertips vainly grasping for the edge!, slide once again into the waiting bowl!

A diagramme:
[image]

Comment: Well, this cauldron is not an exact hemisphere, but a tad more. So, a frictionless hemisphere *can* be escaped, yet modernized like this, indeed cannot. Unless the person inside could grow up nice strong claws and penetrate the surface, or plain break it up into oblivion :)

Comment: I think this might work even if the lower part were just a hemisphere. The key thing is to prevent the inmate from grasping the upper edge of the bowl.

Comment: @DavidK --- Exactly. Key is the upper edge. Whether it's an exact or super or infra hemisphere, if the rim is flat, it's graspable and thus escapable. Old King Crowell opted for slanted rim to give hope without the possibility of attaining said hope. The cauldron shape is purely for entertainment!

Comment: @Vesper --- A pure hemisphere can only be escaped if there is a sufficient rim to grasp. Hence the cauldron shaped rim -- nothing to grasp!

Comment: This might also work with a flat rim if the spherical part of the bowl continues far enough above the equator. At some angle I think there would be two possible outcomes: the prisoner does not have enough speed to stay in contact with the bowl, and falls without being able to reach the edge; or the prisoner has enough speed to reach the edge, but at that point has too much momentum in the direction away from the edge and will slide back into the bowl.

Comment: @DavidK --- Oh, I agree! But dropping a penitent into a long test tube destroys all hope of escape, and thus reduces the hilarity of the punishment! The entire point is for people to be able watch attempted escape after attempted escape, perhaps even cheer on the miscreant when he comes close, but ultimately go home satisfied that Justice has been done.

Comment: I don't mean a long test tube, I mean a spherical bowl whose upper rim is flush with the platform. The idea is that the prisoner might be able to grasp the platform, but the same velocity that enabled them to do so will also prevent them from holding on. The design might take some calculation, including an estimate of the coefficient of friction as the prisoner attempts to hang onto the platform.

Comment: @DavidK --- So long as the penitent slides back down to the bottom in a variety of amusing fashions!

Comment: Am I missing something or can one escape by approaching the top at an angle, say 45°

Comment: @aross --- How do you mean "approach"? The surface is too slick to climb, the bowl too deep and wide to leap out of. Or am *I* missing something?

Comment: @elemtilas I'm talking about the idea of swinging. Just you have to swing in such a way that your motion forms an ellipsoid. Thus when the ellipsoid gets big enough you can approach the edge at an angle instead of at 90 degrees.

Comment: ^ ellipsoid is not quite the right term I'm looking for, but if you would look at it from above it would look like an ellipse.

Comment: @aross --- I'm not certain a person would be able to generate enough motion to do that. Not without some kind of external help. I think the forces at play and relatively small amount of real motion an individual can generate in this circumstance would keep the penitent pretty firmly attached to the glass bowl. Even if a person *could* swing high enough to reach the rim, he wouldn't be able to grasp it, cos there's nothing to hold on to; and the cauldron is too large to leap out of.

Comment: @elemtilas What I'm proposing doesn't require him to grab the edge. He will approach the edge at an angle, then centrifugal force would make stick to the glass even over the edge, and then he would fling onto the platform. Whether he could generate enough motion is debatable of course, as this is already well into fantasy realms... but since there's a hole in the middle, he'll certainly be able to start off his rotational motion with a certain circumference. There's no reason that the swinging physics would not work anymore either.

Comment: @aross --- Perhaps if the cauldron is small enough and the sloped rim shallow enough, that might work. This particular cauldron is noted to be 18 feet in diameter, and the rim appears to be about 3 feet broad and at a steep angle. I agree about the centrifugal force keeping the penitent stuck to the glass. I reckon that, once he reaches the inner rim, that force would no longer be in effect and, *if* he had gained enough momentum (big if) he would naturally head out over the mouth of the cauldron at an approximately 45d angle. I rather doubt he could just "fling" himself a further (cont)

Comment: (cont) 3 to 4 feet that would be required to actually escape. Even with impeccable timing, He'd have nothing against which to apply the leverage needed to change direction. Also, I agree about the shit hole --- I reckon that's about 6 inches in diameter. This is just perfect for someone to "kick off" an escape attempt. A false hope, I think!

Comment: @elemtilas Well let's not attempt this in reality to see what happens. But by approaching the rim at an angle he would fly over the hole at the top, however not right through the middle. His trajectory will "slice off" a very small part of the circle, so the distance traveled in the air will be very short. Imagine riding a full pipe, doing loopings. Turn slightly left, towards a slope, just like the edge of this cauldron. You might jump over that edge and land on the other side pretty much immediately. If you're standing up you could even bend your legs at the right time to prevent the jump.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think a human can escape.

Let us simplify things. You are a two-dimensional person in a frictionless half-pipe. You can place your legs apart and be stable, with your legs at equal angles either side of the vertical. Put your weight on your right foot. The reaction of the half-pipe surface will be perpendicular to the surface. This will give you a slight force to the left. As you move to the left, you are slowed by the curvature. You can do this repeatedly, and put some energy into your oscillation. You can build up some height this way, a bit like pumping on a swing.

You start off effectively being on a 10m swing, so the oscillations are slow, but if you keep at it, you might get somewhere. As you begin to climb the side, the restoring force deviates from simple harmonic motion, and the period becomes longer. As you approach the lip, your pumping efficiency approaches zero, while your speed at the bottom will roughly be given assuming your kinetic energy at the bottom equals your potential energy at the top. With an earth-like g of 10 m/sec^2, you would be going at about 13 m/s, and air resistance would take away any extra energy you could add in an oscillation.

At the edge, you would be going straight up. This does not help but it is not an absolute barrier to getting out. Your centre of gravity may below the edge, but parts of you may briefly get just beyond it. You might even get just beyond the lip of a cauldron if it was a very small one.

Comment: You can get additional force by jumping just before reaching the bottom of the pit and crouching to land slightly up the side. Once you've reached high enough to get above the center of the pit you can get some residual sideways motion by skipping the jump and crouching during the upwards curve. From there it's just a matter of timing.

Comment: I don't see how the pumping efficiency is related to the oscillation amplitude. You pump at the bottom of the pit, not the lip. A swing with a rigid bar instead of a chain can be swung *all the way around* just by the rider pumping their legs, but this suggests they would never be able to go above horizontal as their pumping became useless.

Comment: It the balance between pumping energy in and losing it to air resistance. If you get close to the lip, you are travelling at 30 mph at the bottom. Your ability to pump goes down as the surface gets flatter, until it disappears altogether and you can't move on a flat surface. Maybe someone could get out of a 3m hemisphere, but a 10m one does stay the odds against you a lot IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

This is a straight-up Newtonian mechanics physics question, but it would probably get closed as homework-like on Physics SE, and it's fun, so I'll give you a Newtonian mechanics physics answer here. The answer is yes, as others have said, but it's not quite as others have described it.

Start with a more formal treatment of the mostly correct "oscillate to escape" answers.

Because there is no friction, the prisoner (whose name is Bob$^1$) can only accelerate his center of mass in the direction radially inward from his point of contact with the prison wall.

Because Bob can change his shape, he can temporarily move his point of contact with the prison wall in the tangent direction without accelerating his center of mass in the tangent direction.

Suppose Bob can change his shape such that the displacement between his center of mass and his point of contact, is described by the below triangle:

[image]

The force vector from a thrust at the blue point (the point of contact) will be in the direction of the green side of the triangle.

The proportion of thrust in the tangent direction (at the angle corresponding to the center of mass) is roughly the ratio of the blue segment to the green segment, but if one wants to be precise, it's the ratio of the green line segment to the yellow height of the purple triangle below.

[image]

For green line segment $r$, blue line segment $b$, note that the purple triangle is a similar triangle to the one above it, but with legs $b$, so its height $x$ is the height of the above triangle scaled by the ratio of $b$ to $r$:

$x = \frac{b}{r} \sqrt{r^2 - b^2/4} \approx b \text { for } b \ll r$

If Bob pushes such that his change of momentum is $\Delta \vec P_i$ in the green direction, then his change of velocity in the tangent direction is $\Delta v_i = \frac{x}{rm}|\Delta P_i|$.

If Bob times his changes of shape and his pushes such that his tangent velocity is zero whenever he pushes, each push adds

$\Delta T_i = 0.5m\Delta v_i^2$

until such time as Bob's total mechanical plus potential energy, $\sum \Delta T_i$, is greater than or equal to his potential energy at the height above which a displacement of $b$ puts Bob's point of contact outside of the hemisphere... which prevents him from pushing off, but should permit him to grab the rim and escape.

Bob, however, has a problem that the "oscillate to escape" answers have overlooked. *He is not constrained to stay on the prison wall.*

If Bob had an anchor point mounted at the center of the sphere, to which he had attached a rod that he could push against so as to constrain his motion to the prison wall, escaping would be easy and painless. Bob has no such anchor. While Bob's weight $m\vec g$ is roughly antiparallel to his direction of thrust, Bob is fine. All he needs to do is keep the force of his pushes low enough that gravity can pull his center of mass back down before his point of contact leaves the ground (just like you can stand up and sit down without ever leaping into the air or falling to a bone-jarring halt). However, as Bob reaches the more vertical portions of the wall, if Bob wants to continue adding significant $\Delta T_i$ per oscillation, Bob will have to begin hurling himself off of the wall and suffering impacts from falling.

One may have an intuition that this would prevent Bob from escaping, but this is an intuition based on our experience living in a world with friction: since friction forces increase based on how hard you're pushing on something, if you're pushing on something with the extremely large forces of crashing into it after falling from a significant height, the frictional forces are very large. In his frictionless hemisphere, Bob cannot face*plant*, he can only face*slide*. Hopefully Bob is good at frictionless acrobatics, and can land more comfortably than on his face.

Below: two pushes worth of Bob's later trajectory

[image]

Bob escapes, but only if he's tough enough to take a few hard thumps on the way out.

---

$1$: Alice is on a space ship with a large relative velocity $\vec u$ measuring Bob's escape attempt for next semester's homework assignment.

Comment: When Bob lands back on the ground after leaping, presumably the collision is not perfectly elastic: he is losing some of his energy to deformation. This and the air resistance seem like non-negligible factors for this plan.

Comment: You're right that air resistance is nonnegligible. I suspect that Bob's pushing power (order of 1000N over order of 1m once per period) is a bigger than the air's maximal pushing power (order of 10N over order of 10 meters once per period). However, only one order of magnitude on an order of magnitude estimate is a pretty small safety margin for poor Bob.

Comment: @amalloy The question stipulates a frictionless and rigid surface. Since frictionless is a perfect state, presumably rigid is perfect as well. Therefore we can assume perfectly elastic collisions on the part of the bowl at least. Let's just give our poor prisoner perfectly rigid skates to wear as well.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course the prisoner can escape if left unsupervised.

This is a prison, not a deathtrap; it needs to have the capacity to hold a prisoner over the long term. Particularly, prisoners need to be fed and their waste removed. This requires a mechanism to move things in and out of the prison, and once you have a mechanism to move certain things around, tampering with it to move something else (like the prisoner) is just a matter of time.

Comment: I beg your pardon, but no where in the law codes does it stipulate that penitents must be *fed*.

Comment: Point taken but, theoretically, the _magic_ might exist to move smaller objects but not larger. Having ventilation shafts doesn't mean prisoners can escape using them when they're only a few inches wide.

Comment: I don't understand the logic that if *anything* can get into or out of the cell, even only under very specific controlled circumstances, that the prisoner can therefore free themselves with no outside help. Obviously someone can let the prisoner out, but I find the conclusion that a tiny hole in the floor makes escape inevitable to be nonsensical.

Answer (score 0):

Combining "Bambi on ice" and a gazelle and the slide-swinging part in the previous answer.
The gazelle would swing a bit, to no longer jump straight in the air, but at an angle and jump out.

Answer (score 0):

Since my imagination is running wild in the wizard world you provide.
Birds/Birdman/Pegasi/Dragons can definitely escape this.

They would just fly out.